# Creating objects (JTextfields) inside loop with different names

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Is it possible to create multiple `JTextFields` with different names inside a loop?
I need to so this since I later need to get the text that is in each of them, I need to do something like this:

```
while (sst_ResultSet.next()) {
    p_vertabla.add(new JLabel(sst_ResultSet.getString(1));
    p_vertabla.add(new JTextField(sst_ResultSet.getString(1)));
}
```

This works just fine when adding the `JLabel` and the `JTextField` the way I want it to the `JPanel` `p_vertabla`, but I don't know how to later call the method `.getText();` on the `JTextFields`.

---

How can I create the `JTextFields`in the loop or how can I later call the method on them?

Comment: Could use a `Map`?  `Map<String, JTextField>`, it would be MUCH easier to look up fields later

Comment: Or a `List` of some kind if you just want to run through the list of `JTextField`s.

Comment: would it be possible with an `ArrayList<JTextField>`?

Comment: Yes, if you don't care about the original row from which the data is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question with a little from a comment on the question, I found out that there is no need to assign the variables a name, with an `ArrayList<JtextFiel>` will work, the point is just to follow the order in what they were added to the `JPanel` that way I was able to retrieve the information associated with the `JTextField` in that particular position. I did something like this:

```
ArrayList<JLabel> listadelabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
ArrayList<JTextField> listadetextfields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
ArrayList<JCheckBox> listadecheckbox = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
...
Statement stmt=db.createStatement();
    ResultSet sst_ResultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    JPanel p_obtenerregistro = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,3));
    while (sst_ResultSet.next()) {
        listadelabels.add(new JLabel(sst_ResultSet.getString(1)));
        listadetextfields.add(new JTextField(12));
        listadecheckbox.add(new JCheckBox());
    }
    for(int i=0 ; i<listadelabels.size(); i++){
        listadecheckbox.get(i).addItemListener(this);
        p_obtenerregistro.add(listadecheckbox.get(i));
        p_obtenerregistro.add(listadelabels.get(i));
        listadetextfields.get(i).setEditable(false);
        p_obtenerregistro.add(listadetextfields.get(i));
    }
```

And then to get the info associated with the list I did it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < activos; i++) {
            atributos[i] = listadetextfields.get(arreglodeactivos[i]).getText();
            columnas[i] = listadelabels.get(arreglodeactivos[i]).getText();
            ModificarRegistro.where = ModificarRegistro.where + columnas[i] + "=" + "'" + atributos[i] + "' AND ";
        }
```

I really hope it could useful for a lot of people

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Vector<JTextField>` and add to it the generated items in your for loop:

```
while (sst_ResultSet.next()) {
    p_vertabla.add(new JLabel(sst_ResultSet.getString(1));
    createAndKeepJTextFieldInVector(sst_ResultSet.getString(1));
    // instead of original: p_vertabla.add(new JTextField(sst_ResultSet.getString(1)));
}
```

Then later, you could access any of the JTextFields by calling:

```
String txt = vector.get(index).getText();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I managed to do it with an `ArrayList<JTextfields>`